# How to retry sending email using perl

Tags: perl, sendmail

I'm working on sending email use perl language and use the package Win32::OLE using the CDO object.

my $cdomsg = Win32::OLE->new('CDO.Message');
...
$cdomsg -> Send();

My problem is sometimes there may be some network error or things like that, I want to retry sending the mail 10 times if it didn't send mail successfully. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with that package, but presumably you could check the return satus of the Send() command and loop.

But that's not an elegant solution. This is a problem solved many times over. The better answer is to send the email via SMTP through some real email system. I use Postfix on my Unix boxes, I don't know what the go-to answer is for Windows users. All full-featured email server packages will have a built-in retry solution which will attempt to resend emails for a configurable time period, using an intelligent algorithm to back off on the retry frequency, spacing the retries out over days.